# Python programming _, can't understand what this do the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'am reading a book named Tkinter-by-example. I am fairly new to programming in python. So while I'am typing a sample code in this book I noticed that there is an unfamiliar code to me.

```
colour_schemes = [{"bg": "lightgrey", "fg": "black"}, {"bg": "grey", "fg": "white"}]

_, task_style_choice = divmod(len(self.tasks), 2)

my_scheme_choice = colour_schemes[task_style_choice]
```

I understand how the code works and it runs but for some specific reason whenever I remove this part of the code "_," and i try entering a text this error shows.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I'm using python version 3.6.3 and I can't seem to find any problems related to mine can someone explain to me what "_," this do to my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore is a valid variable name and is commonly used to imply that the value will be unused. Only the second value of the pair returned by `divmod` will be used via the `task_style_choice` variable.

```
_, task_style_choice = divmod(len(self.tasks), 2)
```